# update column with multiple values parsed from current column data

Tags: mysql

Hoping someone can help me with a mysql query

Here’s what I have:

I table with a column “networkname” that contains data like this:

```
“VLAN-338-Network1-A,VLAN-364-Network2-A,VLAN-988-Network3-A,VLAN-1051-Network4-A”
```

I need a MySQL query that will update that column with only the vlan numbers in ascending order, stripping out everything else.  ie.

`“338, 364, 988, 1051”`

Thanks,
David

Comment: Do all the values have four values that you want to extract?

Comment: No, they can vary, as few as one, as many as 30 or more.

Comment: No easy way to do this.  You can think of it as punishment for storing lists of things in a string, rather than having a more normalized format.

Comment: This was a fun one. See my answer below :)

Answer (score 0):

In this script, I create a procedure to loop through the networkname values and parse out the numbers to a separate table, and then update YourTable using a `group_concat` function. This assumes your networkname values follow the 'VLAN-XXX' pattern in your example where 'XXX' is the 3-4 digit number you want to extract. This also assumes each record has a unique ID.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE networkname_parser()
BEGIN
-- load test data
drop table if exists YourTable;
create table YourTable
  (
    ID int not null auto_increment,
    networkname nvarchar(100),
    primary key (ID)
  );
insert into YourTable(networkname) values
  ('VLAN-338-Network1-A,VLAN-364-Network2-A,VLAN-988-Network3-A,VLAN-1051-Network4-A'),
  ('VLAN-231-Network1-A,VLAN-4567-Network2-A'),
  ('VLAN-9876-Network1-A,VLAN-321-Network2-A,VLAN-1678-Network3-A');

-- add commas to the end of networkname for parsing
update YourTable set networkname = concat(networkname,',');

-- parse networkname into related table
drop table if exists ParseYourString;
create table ParseYourString(ID int,NetworkNumbers int);
while (select count(*) from YourTable where networkname like 'VLAN-%') > 0
  do
    insert into ParseYourString
    select ID,replace(substr(networkname,6,4),'-','')
    from YourTable
    where networkname like 'VLAN-%';
    update YourTable
    set networkname = right(networkname,char_length(networkname)-instr(networkname,','))
    where networkname like 'VLAN-%';
  end while;

-- update YourTable.networkname with NetworkNumbers
update YourTable t
    inner join (select ID,group_concat(networknumbers order by networknumbers asc) as networknumbers
                from ParseYourString
                group by ID) n
      on n.ID = t.ID
  set t.networkname = n.networknumbers;
END//
```

Call to procedure and select the results:

```
call networkname_parser();
select * from YourTable;
```

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/01c77/1